# Hover state firing on web app when scrolling

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications, scroll, hover

Creating a web app over here, and the biggest issue I'm facing is that whenever you scroll through the content, all of the hover/active/focus states will fire-off, making it rather annoying.

In a native application, the iPhone or Android app knows the difference between a scroll and a tap. Is there anyway to make this happen with jQuery or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct would be to just add a mouseenter, mouseleave event:

```
$("div").mouseover(function () {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    }, this), 500)
}).mouseout(function () {
    $('div').css("background-color", "");
});
```

The code above will switch background colours of a div, and then clear them all in between the elements. That being said, depending on what your requirements are, and the elements you're working with, it would probably be better not to re-invent the wheel and just use:

**hoverIntent jQuery Plugin**
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Hope that helps!